# enhance performance in XEN VMs when copying lots of files inside the host

Tags: debian, performance, nginx, xen, wordpress

When I copy large amounts of data back and forth on my Debian XEN server in the host-VM, the server response in the webserver-VM with `nginx` becomes very slow.

This is how I cause the problem

1. in the host VM:

   ```
    rsync  -avR /lots/of/files/from/synapse/media_store/ /backup/tmp_matrix_media_store/
   ```
2. in the webserver I monitor the download speed with

   `while true; do echo $(date)" - $({ time -p curl -sSf https://test.org?$RANDOM|grep something; } |& grep real)"; done | tee -a /var/log/nginx/performance.log`

   ```
    Di 23. Mai 09:25:45 UTC 2023 - real 0,73
    Di 23. Mai 09:25:45 UTC 2023 - real 0,20
    ...
   ```

I also tried using `ionice -c2 -n7 rsync -avR  ...` to make the copy process less hungry, but this does not help.

Workaround: If I use `rsync --bwlimit=10M ...` this will slow down the copy progress to max 10 MB/s and and I won't get any problem in the VM.

The server has a CPU :  AMD Ryzen 7 3700X Octa-Core  with 64GB RAM
and the webserver-VM has 4 cores added

What can I do to improve performance?

Comment: Have you tried `ionice -c idle` instead of `-c2`?

Comment: Your tests don't do any disk I/O other than those short log entries, right?